# How can I make a <Route> path trigger "componentDidMount()" for each parameter?

Tags: reactjs

I have this  :

```
<Route path="/management/:entity" component={Pages.ManagementPage}/>
```

And I have a simple `<ul>` list with `<Link>` items :

```
<Link key={index} to={{pathname: entity}} ...//irrelevant details here> 
      <li>Page name here</li>
</Link>
```

Everything works fine when I'm switching between :

1. `localhost:3000/management/entityone` and `localhost:3000/another/route`
2. `localhost:3000/management/entitytwo` and `localhost:3000/another/route`

And in this `ManagementPage` I have a rest call inside `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    let {tablePageIndex,entity} = this.state;
    this.getResultsForPageIndex(tablePageIndex); 
}

getResultsForPageIndex = (pageIndex) => {
    let {resultsPerPage, entityEndpoint} = this.state;
    Api.getPaginatedResults(pageIndex, resultsPerPage, entityEndpoint).then((result => {
        if (result !== 500) {
            this.setState({
                results: result.content,
                tablePageIndex: pageIndex,
                totalResults: result.totalResults
            });
        }
    }))
};
```

But the problem is that this `componentDidMount()` doesn't get called when I'm switching between:

`localhost:3000/management/entityOne` and `localhost:3000/management/entityTwo`, and eventually the results I want to display are not updated. Any suggestions? Thank you.

P.S.: I've built the `ManagementPage` as a React Component:

```
class ManagementPage extends Component { constructor(props) etc.. }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also utilize `componentDidUpdate` for when the route props update. Check the match params and rerun any logic to compute page results.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let {tablePageIndex,entity} = this.state;
  this.getResultsForPageIndex(tablePageIndex); 
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.entity !== this.props.match.params.entitiy) {
    const { tablePageIndex } = this.state;
    this.getResultsForPageIndex(tablePageIndex);
  }
}

getResultsForPageIndex = (pageIndex) => {
    let {resultsPerPage, entityEndpoint} = this.state;
    Api.getPaginatedResults(pageIndex, resultsPerPage, entityEndpoint).then((result => {
        if (result !== 500) {
            this.setState({
                results: result.content,
                tablePageIndex: pageIndex,
                totalResults: result.totalResults
            });
        }
    }))
};
```

Comment: @SebastianI. Maybe. If you update your question to include more of the component, like the constructor/state, and the render function where it's used.

Comment: @SebastianI. Looks like it is a similar issue. `BasePage` appears to only set state in the constructor, so any page like `ManagementPage` that *may* be passing updated props may not be updating the `activePageName` state of `BasePage`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to react but I'd try to add a componentDidUpdate where you check if the params did change and if they did recall

```
this.getResultsForPageIndex(tablePageIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.unlistenHistory = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
        //Do for every url change
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlistenHistory();
}
```

of course you should export your component withRouter from react-router for calling this.props.history